# I want to install CoCoA in linux but i am unable to do so?

Tags: software-installation

I have elementary Loki as my OS
http://cocoa.dima.unige.it/
Here is what I tried. I unzipped the file (which went well) and then typed ./configure which threw me an error that such a directory doesn't exist. Now I don't know what I should do. I found this document http://fe.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/icms2010-dvd/CoCoA/Mac/Install%20CoCoA.pdf for older version but even this doesn't work for me. So can anyone try installing it and then let me know the step by step procedure.

Comment: "an error" is not particularly helpful.  What is the exact error message you received, in response to what exact command?

Comment: bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: comment was ./configure

Comment: Presumably when you extracted the archive, it went into a newly-created directory.  Did you `cd` into that directory before running `./configure`?

Comment: yes i did that, i followed this tutorial http://ccm.net/faq/14903-how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file-on-ubuntu

Comment: What file did you download and unzip, exactly? what is the output of `ls` in the directory in which you are trying to execute `./configure`?

Comment: I downloaded the file mentioned in the question (the first link), then I graphically unzipped that file, then i cd to the newly created unzipped folder and then I typed ./configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two `CoCoA` webpages which seem to provide some guidance:

This first gives a link to the download for CoCoA-5 and then explains the installation:
http://cocoa.dima.unige.it/download/install5-unix.shtml

The next link has screenshots related to installing and setting it up:
http://cocoa.dima.unige.it/download/screenshots.shtml

The only `configure`-like command that is referenced is `./ConfigEmacs.sh`.  Previous versions of `CoCoA` also do not mention the `./configure` command.

Comment: thanks it worked, I thought that command was for installing emacs

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh If this answer solved your problem, please indicate that by [marking it as accepted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to it.